# General Regex confusion. Trying to verify phone number

Tags: c#, regex

So it seems everything I do with Regex doesn't do what I expect it to do.  This statement, I expect to toss out any letters and require 3 digits at minimum and most, but it doesn't require 3 digits.  It indeed disallows letters but any number of digits is good.

```
myReg = new Regex(@"(^[a-z])([0-9]{3,3})*");
```

I expect the ^[a-z] to toss out letters and the [0-9]{3,3} to require 3 digits.

Might as well add the whole code block, wasn't thinking.

```
userData = phone.Text;

myReg = new Regex(@"(^[a-z])([0-9]{3})+");

        foreach (var validName in myReg.Matches(userData))
        {
            if (myReg.IsMatch(userData))
            {
                phone.Clear();
                badData.Visible = true;
                phone.Focus();
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, that was a copy/paste error.  Fixed that typo!

Comment: You have conflicting requirements: 3 at minimum and most vs. any number of digits. Which is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That matches

```
One character that isn't a letter from a to f, stored in a backreference,
followed by zero or more instances of: 
    3 characters that are digits from 0-9
    stored in another backreference.
```

I think you need: `^[0-9]{3}+$`

This matches a string that contains:

```
One or more instances of:
    3 characters that are digits from 0-9
```

If you instead simply need a string that consists of more than 3 characters and entirely of digits, you can use:`^[0-9]+$`

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead to require exactly three digits:

```
var regex = new Regex(@"^\d{3}$");
```

Comment: That accepts everything BUT 3 digits.  Is it my other code that is faulty?

Comment: Check your casing. `\d` means match only digits. `\D` means match everything except digits.

Comment: @user1664300 it seems to be working fine here: http://www.rubular.com/r/O8I2FssWGD

Comment: Reading the question I think the user wants to *skip* letters, as in ignoring them, not the regexp to fail. That's indeed still missing from the answer

Answer (score 0):

I think the * is specifying that you can put any amount of characters. Try to remove the "*" and see if it works.

Comment: Removing the '*' makes a-z valid characters and makes it so it kicks out any more than 2 digits, so 23 is valid but 123 isn't

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
"(\+?\d{1,5}(?:[\s_-]{0,1}\d{2,4}[\s_-])+)"
```

Comment: That is overkill for what the OP requires, no?

Answer (score 0):

```
^(?=.{3,10})([2-9]\d{2,9})
```

- `^(?=.{3,10})` From the start there must be at least 3 items but no more than 10
- `[2-9]`        No US number can start with a 1, so make sure that a range of 2-9 is the range for the 1st number is allowed.
- `\d{2,9}`      States that 2 more up to 9 numerics must be in the match.